# WKWebView body onclick ignored

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I have a simple html string loaded into my `WKWebView`:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onclick='alert("Success")'>
    <p>Click me</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The `UIDelegate` is correctly set up. The `onclick` handler does not react though. If I set the `onclick` handler onto the `<p>` tag, it works fine. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having stumbled upon the same problem: As Wojciech says, an onclick listener on body will never fire (as of iOS 9.3) in WKWebView.

I solved this by adding an intermediate `<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">` as a container and putting `onclick` there. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the onclick. WKWebView silently ignores "notifications" that you're trying to make with JS, including alert().

So, to make sure the JS is working you should use the message handlers (as described here: http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/) and pass your messages using JS.

Comment: In my experience, even cases that don't involve `alert()` are still ignored. Neither `UIDelegate` nor `navigationDelegate` are notified on taps, not even on anchor elements which lack `href` attributes—and all of this previously worked under `UIWebView`.

Comment: It is about the click. I can trigger a message just fine (```webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(\"documentclicked\");```), but it won't fire in onclick.